# Sens de "Mais d'où qu'y sort çui-là !"

Tags: sens, argot

J'ai lu [ici](https://www.franceinter.fr/emissions/la-bas-si-j-y-suis/la-bas-si-j-y-suis-03-decembre-2012) la tournure

> Mais d'où qu'y sort çui-là !

Je pense que y sort désigne il sort. Qu'est-ce que **çui-là** ? Quelle est le sens alors de la phrase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour **çui-là** il s'agit tout simplement de celui là

**Signification :** Mais d'ou est ce qu'il vient celui la ?

**Exemple :** Si jamais deux amis se parlent et qu'un troisième apparait subitement l'un des deux amis pourrait dire :

> Mais d'où qu'y sort çui-là?

Autrement dit : Lorsque l'on s'interroge sur une apparition *(brutale ou impromptue)* d'une personne ou même d'un objet ..